# NetLogo LevelSpace Extension for Passing Agents Between Models

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm using NetLogo's LevelSpace extension to pass agents between two models.

Specifically, I am wanting to make agents leave one model and appear with all of their attributes in another model, and vice versa.

For example, if one model was of a work environment and an agent spent 8 hours at work then, the other model was of the agent's home. That same agent would have all of the same attributes, just be in a different environment. The agent would need to have their attributes updated in each model as well.

I currently have a controller setup to control both model environments and, hopefully, will be able to record and plot data received from both models but I need to be able to pass the agents back and forth first. Does anyone know if this is actually possible and how to achieve it. The LevelSpace dictionary doesn't really have a solution and I can't find a tutorial.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is, how do I make this happen. Thanks for pointing that out for me though.

Comment: Have you looked into the following example code for passing variables between two models:  https://github.com/NetLogo/LevelSpace#a-general-use-case-inter-model-interactions Instead of a variable, you may be able to pass an agentset, or alternatively a list of attributes for each agent (then reconstruct in the other model).